# Google OAuth2 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-oauth

My client is use `other` type
[image]

I have no idea why i get `redirect_uri_mismatch` error. It work on localhost but not on domain.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client type other is for installed applications it should not have a redirect uri the way it works is it returns the authorization code directly back where it came from that being

- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

For some reason your code is sending a https redirect uri which is in correct it should not be doing this.  It looks like you are using the code for a web browser application with a native application client.

Comment: my app is web application but i do auth all in java, so should i change client type to 'webapp'?

Comment: If you are using a web application then yes you should have a browser client.  Remember to set the redirect uri up.